# Not able to disable keyboard appearing automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The moment I come on this page the keyboard appears automatically, I want to disable that.When someone press on the enter email.I want keyboard to come at that time only.
I have tried every thing nothing seems to work.Can someone please help me out

```
Form(
    child: Column(
      children: [
       TextFormField(
       // focusNode: fEmail,
       onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
          // fEmail!.unfocus();
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(fPass);
       },
       textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
       autofocus: true,
       style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
       decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
         ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
         onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
           fPass!.unfocus();
           FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
           // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(fButton);
         },
         focusNode: fPass,
         textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
         autofocus: true,
         style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
         decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Enter Your PassWord',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
         ),
        ),
       ],
      ),
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use focus Node to control the behaviour.
if you put `autofocus: true` if your code. this line will automatically focus on the top most Textfield widget.

put `autofocus: false` in our code it will be disable your keyboard which is opening automatically in the text filed.

Refer Focus and text fields: [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus)

Refer autofocus property: [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofocus.html)

Comment: copy paste from my answer just some chnages @Chandan Pradhan

Comment: you did right answer but for any developer you need to explain your point I just explained and i provided documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `autofocus: true,` from your code or set it to `autofocus: false`,

Refer Focus and text fields [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus)

Refer autofocus property [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofocus.html)

Comment: Oooh Okaay Thaank you so much Ravindra :D for always helping me out, and helping me become a better programmer :D

Comment: Most Welcome @KavachDheer happy to help you, Enjoy your ride with flutter

Answer (score 2):

You can use focus node to control the behaviour.

If you put `autofocus=true` in your code it will automatically focus on the topmost textfield widget in the current tree.

put `autofocus = false` or remove the parameter as it is `false` by default.

Comment: Oooh Okaay Thaank you so much Sparsh. :D